# How to convert format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss in logstash

Tags: logstash

I fetch the data through Oracle, and the database has a field updated_at in the format "*yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss*".
However, it has been automatically changed to ISO8601 format in logstash.
So I try to change the format "*yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss*", but I get an error like _dateparsefailure.
Here is my config file.
What is the problem?

```
input {
   jdbc {
        jdbc_validate_connection => true
        jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/jars/ojdbc8.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
        jdbc_connection_string => <connection string>
        jdbc_user => <my username>
        jdbc_password => <my password>
        use_column_value => true
        statement => "SELECT * FROM IP_INFO"
        schedule => "*/1 * * * *"
        charset => "UTF-8"
        enable_metric => false
   }

}

filter {
    date {
        match => [
            "updated_at", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        ]
        target => "updated_at"
    }
}

output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

**Result**

```
{
    "@timestamp" => 2020-10-14T07:34:03.755Z,
    "updated_at" => 2020-10-14T04:44:37.000Z,
    "tags" => [
        [0] "_dateparsefailure"
    ],
    "created_at" => 2020-09-29T15:56:37.000Z
}
```

So, I just convert updated_at and created_at field to "*yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss*".
Can you help me?

Comment: Could you send a sample of data which will be parser by logstash?

Comment: Input data is 2020-10-14 04:59:28. same format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss. But it automatically changed to iso8601 format.

Comment: perhaps your fields are already date, so the date parse fails?

Comment: yes. as you can see, I don't know why

Answer (score 1):

The use of date filter is to parse a timestamp and produce an ISO8601 timestamp that Elasticsearch automatically treats as a date. Anything else is not identified as date so you will not be able to treat the field as date in queries.